# Jquery dialog-box is not functioning after I have implemented the lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, lightbox

Here is my code, now lightbox is working. Dialogbox only works when we remove the lightbox scripts. Can anyone suggest what may be the reason for the dialog box is not loading?. on the chrome console it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null

```
<?php
    include 'header.inc.php';
    $floor_id=$_GET['id'];
    $path='floorPlanImages';
    //include 'addImageForPlan.php';
    $select_floor_images=mysql_query("SELECT id,image FROM zb_floorplan_gallery WHERE floor_id='$floor_id'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($select_floor_images)>0)
    {
    ?>

    <html lang="en">
    <!doctype html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />




    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  
    </head>

    <table>

        <tr><th colspan="5">Image gallery</th></tr>
        <tr>

    <?php
    $count=0;
    while ($display_image=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_floor_images)) {

        ?>
        <td class="<?php echo $display_image['id'];?>" height="100" width="100">

        <!-- <img src="<?php echo $path.'/'.$display_image['image'];?>" width="100%" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" class="<?php echo $display_image['id'];?>"></a> -->&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <a href="<?php echo $path.'/'.$display_image['image'];?>" rel="lightbox[gallery]" title="Floor Plan images">
            <img src="<?php echo $path.'/'.$display_image['image'];?>" width="100%" >
         </a>

           <a href="#" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete" id="<?php echo $display_image['id'];?>"></a></td>
        <?php
        $count++;
        if($count==4)
        {
        ?></tr><?php $count=0;
        }

    ?>


    <script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready(function() {


            $('#<?php echo $display_image['id'];?>').click(function(){
            $( '#<?php echo $display_image['id'];?>').html("Are you sure you want to delete this image?").dialog(
                {

                     buttons: {
        'Confirm': function() {
           //do something
           $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "deleteFloorImage.php?id=<?php echo $display_image['id'];?>",
      data: { id: "<?php echo $display_image['id'];?>" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {

    $("td.<?php echo $display_image['id'];?>").hide();

    });
           $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
           $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
                }
            );
            });




      });
      </script>



    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>


    <?php
    }
    else {
        echo 'No images found for this floor plan';
    }
    include 'footer.inc.php';
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch your DOM to find the error.

Maybe it's a jquery conflict with lib.

Try to write `jQuery.noConflict();`   before :

```
$( document ).ready(function().....
```

And put your lib :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

just after calling your jquery lib

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tired the above but no luck. Is there any other method to implement these two on the same page?